# android pass variable from one method to another

Tags: java, android, variables, if-statement, methods

I am working on this android `wearable` app for my own use and am stuck on how to pass a variable from within a `if statement` within a method to another method..

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String myYards = "";
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    curhole = extras.getInt("hole");
    if(curhole == 1){
        myYards = "325";
        double lat2 = 39.657479;
        double lon2 = -121.778788;
    }
    if(curhole == 2){
        myYards = "191";
        double lat2 = 39.255478;
        double lon2 = -121.125547;
    }
    TextView holeyard = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.holeYard);
    holeyard.setText(String.valueOf(myYards + " yards"));

    if(googleApiClient.isConnected()){
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    myLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    Location loc1 = new Location("");
    loc1.setLatitude(myLatitude);
    loc1.setLongitude(myLongitude);
    Location loc2 = new Location("");
    loc2.setLatitude(lat2);
    loc2.setLongitude(lon2);
    float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
    int myDist = (int) (distanceInMeters * 1.0936);
    TextView latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yardage);
    latView.setText(String.valueOf(myDist));
}
```

I would like to change the `gps coordinates` based on the whole number within the `if statements` in the `onStart()` method and pass them to the `onLocationChanged()` method, is this possible? Or am I just going about this wrong as I am new to android..

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you call `onLocationChanged()`? It will be called by the OS itself when the location is changed/updated.

Comment: I am using the Fused Location API and in the tutorial it says to do it like that to get the location to auto update my distance as it changes, is there a better way @Sufian ?

Comment: @RyanD uf so - ask Fused Location API creator why it is not working when the tutorial says it should work. Sufian gives you the point what can be wrong.

Comment: Besides, you are mention some methods that are not included in provided snippets eg. `onStart` while you are asking about flow controll from that method's body.

Comment: Wait....so can't you just pass it as a Location object to the actual method itself. Question is very confusing. Pase the onStart method please

Comment: @RyanD could you share the link where it days that you have to call `onLocationChanged ()` yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put these variables in your class, then all methods from class have access to them.

for example in class:
double x;

in statematent:
x= ...